# How to Save data when application is in background bluetooth mode?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I know, from documentation, that iOS application can scan for BLE devices when it is in background mode. It can also retrieve data form peripherals devices.

#### Question

What can I do with this data. My purpose is to save this data (after deserialize of course) to core data. How can I do that?

If this is not possible, what is the recommended way to do it? (NSUserDefaults and after sync with CoreData?)

(iOS10, Swift3)

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to save it to core data? The only thing you need to be aware of is that the file protection formyiur core data file allows you to write while the device is locked; probably https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfileprotectioncompleteuntilfirstuserauthentication

Comment: And it will be enough to save data to core data, when application is in background mode? I am not sure that I am asking. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in background an app registered to BLE event will be awaken by the system in occurrence of BLE related event that you are registered for. Then the appropriate delegate methods will be called as documented in the official apple documentation.

Events that will awake your app from the BLE are notifications, new peripheral if you are in discovery mode, new connection events (connection/disconnection).

From the moment the app is awaken by the system you have roughly 8 seconds to execute your code and respond to the BLE update. In this time window you can perform any kind of operation you wish, including core data related jobs.

Please consider to read this document released by apple to help developers to develop amazing apps that works with BLE: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

Comment: from your experience 8 sec is enough to save something to persistent store and/or save context?

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to save and how efficient is your code in the update algorithm. In general it is more than enough unless you ar saving thousands objects in a very non efficient way.

Comment: tnk @Giuseppe Lanza Im going to mark this answer as answered

Comment: What happens if the bluetooth peripheral keeps sending continuous data all the time (for example during driving continuous car data)